# how to extract all click counts per url or link name for specific jobs using data views?

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, dataextensions, sql, data

I would like to use data view _CLICK to extract all a list of all clicked URLs along with the count (how many unique subscribers clicked on the link) for specific job ids.

Can anyone help me with the approach? This is what I got so far

```
SELECT c.JobID, j.EmailName, c.LinkName, c.LinkContent, c.URL, c.IsUnique, count(*) as Total_Count
FROM _Click c
INNER JOIN _Job j ON j.JobID = c.JobID
where c.JobID IN ('123456','111111')
and c.IsUnique = 'true'
GROUP BY c.jobid, c.URL
```

Basically I am looking for an output like this:

| JobID | URL | LinkName | Total_Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) | CTA_1 | 10 |
| 1 | [www.yahoo.com](http://www.yahoo.com) | CTA_2 | 4 |
| 2 | [www.hotmail.com](http://www.hotmail.com) | link_top | 50 |
| 2 | [www.spacex.com](http://www.spacex.com) | footer_link | 10 |

It would be great to include email name in the output (if possible).

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** I ended up creating the query

```
SELECT TOP 1000 c.JobID, MAX(j.EmailName) AS EmailName, c.LinkName, c.URL, c.IsUnique, count(distinct c.SubscriberID) as Total_Count
FROM _Click c WITH (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN _Job j WITH (NOLOCK) ON j.JobID = c.JobID
where c.JobID IN ('123456','111111')
and c.IsUnique = 'true'
GROUP BY c.jobid, c.URL, c.LinkName, c.IsUnique
ORDER BY c.jobid, count(distinct c.SubscriberID) desc
```